# Does twitter rest api give only a sample of the data?

Tags: rest, twitter

Lets say I want to get all the tweets from a user that have 10k(or more) tweets, would I be able to go back with the twitter rest api and get all the user statuses? or only a sample would be given.

Does twitter give you only sample for some case with the rest api? like on search or something like that.
What are the restrictions of the rest api? aside the rate limits

I know the [streaming api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055370/how-many-percent-of-the-tweets-does-twitter-sample-api-give) is limited to a ~1% of the data. But I'm not certain of the rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the endpoint the number of tweets you can retrieve varies. In the case of tweets from a user you should use [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline).

According to the documentation of this endpoint:

> This method can only return up to **3,200** of a user’s most recent Tweets. Native retweets of other statuses by the user is included in this total, regardless of whether include_rts is set to false when requesting this resource.

If you have all the tweet ids from an user, you could retrieve all by ids by using [GET statuses/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup)

Streaming API can help you, but only for the next tweets because it's realtime. Remember that this 1% is related to all tweets in the world and usually all tweets from a user will be returned on that connection, given that 1% means 5 million tweets/day